# Get regions containing a coordinate in Overpass-API

Tags: openstreetmap, area, overpass-api

I am using the Overpass-API to access OSM data. I want to retrieve all relations or ways (*don't really know which of them, since I'm very new to this...*) containing a given coordinate. I thought of using the `way(around:10, lat, lon)` selector of the API but this seems to only give ways where one defining node is inside a circle with radius 10 around the position.

Is there any way to come around this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can find the solution via the is_in parameter of overpass-api?

see these postings:

- http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=29128
- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Query_for_areas_.28is_in.29][2](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Query_for_areas_.28is_in.29)
- https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/48088/what-makes-a-closed-way-show-up-as-an-enclosing-feature-with-query-features

Comment: yeah, I saw the is_in parameter for overpass querys, however this operater only works with areas as input sets. areas on the other hand are only defined for postal codes, administrative divisions, etc. I sadly cannot use `is_in(lon,lat)way`

Comment: @RenéMartin: you need to use `way(pivot)` to get back the original way. The question would also be, what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: Yeah you are right, I could get the way of the surrounding administrative areas but what I'm looking for are surrounding ways like park borders, coastlines, riversides, forests, etc.